# Where and how topic does get created in broker when script with details on number of partition and replica factor is given

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

when we create topic ,where we decide number of partition and replica factor.
Do this topic get created in all the brokers?
Is it specific to any one broker?

Answer (score 0):

You are required to pass replication factor and partitions when creating topics.

One which broker(s) each partition and replica are placed, are randomly decided, although you can later use `kafka-reassign-partitions` to move replicas around to other brokers.

Answer (score 0):

You can crate a topic with this command:

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper <ZOOKEEPER_URL:PORT> --replication-factor <NO_OF_REPLICATIONS> --partitions <NO_OF_PARTITIONS> --topic <TOPIC_NAME>
```

After this command metadata about the topic (number of partitions, replicas, ISR list etc.) is stored in Zookeeper. You can get information about topic by this command:

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic TopicName --describe
```

Replica list of partitions are created according to round-robin algorithm and Controller broker is responsible for noticing new topic creation and triggering partitions assignment.

Comment: Latest scripts use bootstrap servers rather than Zookeeper

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes. Prior to version 2.2 only zookeeper could be used. But after that both bootstrap-server and zookeeper are valid options. reference: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-377%3A+TopicCommand+to+use+AdminClient